# How can I enable auto-replace patterns like :alpha: for "Language = [None]" text in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-impress

*This question is written as Q&A after having found an answer.*

The feature of LibreOffice of inserting unicode characters using sequences such as `:alpha:` or `:_1:` could be useful for writing equations, e.g. inline equations in Libreoffice Impress, where the equation editor is not available. It could also be used e.g. for writing Emails.

This could be combined with a character style, that sets the language to `[None]` in order to prevent the spell checker from acting on that text. However, doing so disables these replacement rules.

Is it somehow possible to enable the replacement rules for such text?

Answer (score 0):

As of LibreOffice 7.6, `[None]` language regions use autocorret replacement rules defined for the language `[All]` in *Tools > AutoCorrect > AutoCorrect Options > Replace*. Despite the naming, the `[All]` setting does not affect *all* languages, but *only* the `[None]` language. Currently there does not seem to be a functional way to define replacements, that *actually* apply to *all* languages.

The replacement rules are (sadly) defined for each language separately, including language-independent rules like `:alpha:`.

Manually copying over the rules would not be viable. Instead it can be done on the level of configuration files. For simplicity, I assume starting from `English (USA)`.

1. Add some arbitrary rule to both the `[All]` and the `English (USA)` replacement rules. I chose `:etc:` being replaced by `et cetera`. This ensures, that user configuration files exist, which will contain *all* currently defined replacement rules.
2. Look up the configuration paths under *Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Paths*. There should be a line "AutoCorrect" giving "User Paths". For me on Linux this was `/home/USERNAME/.config/libreoffice/4/user/autocorr`
3. Go to that directory. It should contain several `acor_LANG.dat` files, one for each language with user-modifications.
4. Replace `acor_und.dat` by a copy of `acor_en-US.dat`.

After restarting LibreOffice, the `[All]` language should now contain the same entries as `English (USA)`. Future changes need to be manually applied to both languages.

**Note.** If LibreOffice adds more rules out of the box in the future, these rules will probably be masked by the customizations, which were initialized to contain an older list of default rules. The same happens when customizing hotkeys or menus; LibreOffice stores customizations as complete configurations rather than as change sets relative to the default settings.